# Как вставить новую строку в таблицу Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, bootstrap

Делаю AJAX запрос-получаю данные . Вывожу их в таблицу. Проблема состоит в том, что без перезагрузки страницы не применяются стили Bootsrap к добавленной строке.

Код Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$('.addNew').click(function (e) {

    $('.modal').modal('toggle');
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:'/index1',
        data:{
            'name':$('#name_ajax').val(),
            'parent_id':$('#parent_ajax').val()
        },
        success:function (data) {

              $('#table_result tr:last').after("<tr><td>"+data.id+"</td><td>"+data.name+"</td><td>"+data.parent_id+"</td></tr>")
        }

    })
})
```

})

Шаблон

```
  @extends('master')
@section('content')
    @include('_partial.errors')
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
        Add new
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
         aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <label class="">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name_ajax" class="form-control">
                    <label class="">Parent_id</label>
                    <input type="text" name="parent_id" id="parent_ajax" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary addNew">Add New</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="result"></div>
    <div class=" table-responsive">

        <table class="table table-hover " id="table_result">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>N</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Parent_id</th>
                <th>Show Edit Delete</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            @foreach($items as $item)

                <tbody>
                <th>{{$item->id}}</th>
                <th>{{$item->name}}</th>
                <th>{{$item->parent_id}}</th>
                <th>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger delete_ajax" value="{{$item->id}}">Del</button>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <form action="" method="post">
                        {{ method_field('Delete') }}
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                        <input type="submit" class="btn-success send">
                    </form>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <a href="/ajax" class="btn btn-success btn-block ">Send Ajax</a>
                </th>
                </tbody>
            @endforeach
        </table>
    </div>

    <p><b></b>
    </p>
@endsection
```

В принципе можно залезть в bootsrap.css и оттуда взять стили, но хочется более элегантное решение

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, пример где это воспроизводится.

Answer (score 0):

У вас внутри `<tbody>` нет теги строки `<tr>`. Таким образом скрипт вставляет строки после последней найденной строки `<tr>` внутри `<thead>`.
А также, цикл `@foreach` надо расположить внутри `<tbody>`:

```
<table>
  <thead>...</thead>
  <tbody>
  @foreach($items as $item)
    <tr>...</tr>
  @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Исправил. Но проблема не решена.

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `$('#table_result tr:last')` на `$('#table_result tr:last-child')` в success функции